# dygraphs extra download not working

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I'm trying to add a download button to an R app, using shiny and dygraphs extra.

I tried to build it like in the example that comes this dygraphs extra: https://github.com/joh024/dygraph-extra/tree/master/shiny-example

My problem is the app shows the download button, when I click it the URL changes to URL/# as specified in the accompanying R script for dygraph-extra.js, but no download occurs.

I've already updated all packages, but it still doesn't work.

Here's the ui code

```
tabItem(tabName = "bodenwasserchemie_plot",
sidebarPanel(width=3,
                h4(em("Bitte wählen Sie aus!"), style= "color:orange"),
                selectInput('bfi_80_bowa', h5('BFI:'), as.character(BFI_bodenwasser$bfi_80_name),selected ='Kitzbuehel'),
                selectInput('plot_bowa', h5('Plot Nummer:'), as.character(PLOT_NR_bodenwasser$plot_nr),selected ='701'),
                selectInput('tiefe_bowa',h5('Tiefe:'), as.character(TIEFE$tiefe),selected ='15'),
                selectInput('par_bowa',h5('Parameter:'), as.character(PAR_BOWA$par),selected = 'ph')
            ),
            tags$head(
            tags$script(src = "dygraph-extra.js")
            ),
            box(title= "Bodenwasserchemie", status="primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
            dyDownload("dyout", "Download Plot", asbutton = TRUE),
            dygraphOutput("dyout", height=600)
            )
        )
```

and the server code

```
bowa_zeitreihe <- reactive({
    qry<-paste0("SELECT probenahme_datum, ", input$par_bowa, " AS wert FROM gea.cl_bfi_80 RIGHT JOIN gea.bodenwasserchemie ON gea.cl_bfi_80.bfi_80_code=gea.bodenwasserchemie.bfi_80 WHERE bfi_80_name= '",input$bfi_80_bowa,"' AND plot_nr=",input$plot_bowa," AND tiefe=", input$tiefe_bowa," ORDER BY probenahme_datum")
    bowa_z <- dbGetQuery(con, qry)
    rownames(bowa_z)<-bowa_z$probenahme_datum
    daten<-as.xts(bowa_z)
    daten
    })
  output$dyout = renderDygraph({dygraph(bowa_zeitreihe(),xlab="Datum",ylab=input$par_bowa) %>%
    dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("2016-01-01", "2017-01-01")) %>%
    dyOptions(drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2) %>% 
    dySeries("wert", label = input$par_bowa) %>%
    dyCallbacks(drawCallback = dyRegister())
    })
```

It seems some people have solved a similar problem with the package webshots, but I'd rather continue with dygraphs extra. Also I think it's probably just a small thing that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. We had to enter the sourcefile manually and there was a spelling mistake in the path, which is why R wasn't able to use dygraphs-extra and at the same time didn't put out an error. The code as written above works perfectly fine.